# Can I add additional type that will combine multiple json properties when deserializing JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

The original JSON C# class structure looks like

```
 public class Main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
        public double temp_max { get; set; }
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        public double sea_level { get; set; }
        public double grnd_level { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public double temp_kf { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clouds
    {
        public int all { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public double deg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Snow
    {
        public double? 3h { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sys
    {
        public string pod { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rain
    {
        public double 3h { get; set; }
    }

    public class List
    {
        public int dt { get; set; }
        public Main main { get; set; }
        public IList<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public Snow snow { get; set; }
        public Sys sys { get; set; }
        public string dt_txt { get; set; }
        public Rain rain { get; set; }
    }

    public class Coord
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lon { get; set; }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public string cod { get; set; }
        public double message { get; set; }
        public int cnt { get; set; }
        public IList<List> list { get; set; }
        public City city { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to remove some properties and merge other into my types, so at the end I want to get next C# class structure:

```
public class WeatherForecast
    {
        [JsonProperty("city")]
        public City City { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("list")]
        public IList<ClimateIndicators> ClimateIndicators { get; set; }
    }

 public class ClimateIndicators
    {
        public Atmospheric Atmospheric { get; set; }
        public Hydrospheric Hydrospheric { get; set; }
        public Lithospheric Lithospheric { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public IList<WeatherDetails> WeatherDetails { get; set; }
    }

 public class Atmospheric
    {
        [JsonProperty("pressure")]
        public double Pressure { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("humidity")]
        public int Humidity { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("sea_level")]
        public double SeaLevel { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("grnd_level")]
        public double GroundLevel { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("all")]
        public int Cloudiness { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("rain")]
        public double? Rain { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("snow")]
        public double? Snow { get; set; } 
    }
```

I am adding custom classification for the weather conditions. So the problem I am facing is that I don't know how to merge multiple JSON Properties into a single class that is a property of another JSON property.

Comment: Where is your json?

Comment: What is the JSON you are trying to deserialize, and what is the mapping between it and the new model that you are trying to achieve?  Also, your desired model is missing a bunch of classes.  What is the definition of `Hydrospheric`, `Lithospheric` and `WeatherDetails`?

Comment: @BrianRogers http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Just ignore those three. I want to combine Clouds Wind Snow and Main into Atmospheric class. How can I create  Atmospheric object upon deserialization and move those properties into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the class structure you want has a different shape than the JSON, you will need to create a custom `JsonConverter` to bridge the differences.  In your case, the `WeatherForecast` and `City` classes don't need any special handling (just using the `[JsonProperty]` attributes is sufficient), but the `ClimateIndicators` class definitely needs a converter.

Here is what it would look like in code.  The converter works by loading the JSON data for each item of the `list` array into a temporary `JObject`.  (Json.Net calls `ReadJson` once for each item, so that is why there is no loop in the converter.)  From there, `SelectToken` is used to pick out the values from the various nested item properties needed to populate an instance of the `ClimateIndicators` class and its supporting class `Atmospheric`.  The `ClimateIndicators` instance is then returned to Json.Net, which automatically adds it to the list in the `WeatherForecast` class.

```
class ClimateIndicatorsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ClimateIndicators);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        Atmospheric atm = new Atmospheric();
        atm.Pressure = (double)obj.SelectToken("main.pressure");
        atm.Humidity = (int)obj.SelectToken("main.humidity");
        atm.SeaLevel = (double)obj.SelectToken("main.sea_level");
        atm.GroundLevel = (double)obj.SelectToken("main.grnd_level");
        atm.Cloudiness = (int)obj.SelectToken("clouds.all");
        atm.Rain = (double?)obj.SelectToken("rain.3h");
        atm.Snow = (double?)obj.SelectToken("snow.3h");

        ClimateIndicators indicators = new ClimateIndicators();
        indicators.Atmospheric = atm;
        indicators.Date = (DateTime)obj.SelectToken("dt_txt");

        return indicators;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the `ClimateIndicators` class like this:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ClimateIndicatorsConverter))]
    public class ClimateIndicators
    {
        ...
    }
```

Note that you do not need `[JsonProperty]` attributes on the properties within the `ClimateIndicators` or `Atmospheric` class, because the property mapping is being handled by the converter.

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fc9G69